# Why does OBJECT element always 100% of html width despite SVG scaling proportions

Tags: html, svg, flexbox, responsive-images, html-object

Can someone please explain why, when my SVG image shrinks in height and its width shrinks proportionally to achieve true scaling, that the width of the OBJECT tag/element still demands 100%

See [here](https://github.com/RichardMaher/ScaleIt) for an SSCCE.

See [GitHub pages](https://RichardMaher.github.io/ScaleIt/test_svg.html) (case-sensitive URLs) for a working example. SVG is too big to include here.

Here's the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="application/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("load", () =>
        {
            var imageDOM = document.getElementById("crest").contentDocument;
            var svgRoot = imageDOM.querySelector(':root');
            svgRoot.style.setProperty('--coa-bg-color', '#ffd700');
            
            var crest = imageDOM.getElementById("wa_state_crest");
        });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
:root {
  --main-bg-color: #002f5f;
  --coa-body-color: #ffd700;
}
    @-ms-viewport{
        width: device-width;
        height: auto;
    }   
    *, *:before, *:after{
        box-sizing: inherit;
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
        -moz-user-select: none;
    }       
    ::-ms-clear{
        display: none;
    }       
    html, body{
        margin: 0px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        -ms-overflow-style: none;
        -ms-content-zooming: none;
        touch-action: manipulation;
    }
    body {
        background-image: radial-gradient(#fff, #1ecbe1, #ADD8E6);
        overscroll-behavior: none;
        pointer-events: auto;
        display: flex;
        font-size: 14px;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100vh;
        padding: 1em;
    }   
    
    .wholeScreen{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 0px;
    }   

    div#headerDiv{
        display: flex;
        order: 1;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0.5em;
        align-items: center;
        flex-grow: 10;
        flex-shrink: 10;
        flex-basis: 10%;
        color: var(--coa-body-color);
        text-shadow: 0 -.3em .3em #fff;
    }

.field__items {
        display: flex;
        order: 2;
        align-items: center;
        flex-grow: 90;
        flex-shrink: 90;
        flex-basis: 90%;
        min-height: 0;
}
.field__item {
    display: flex;
    order: 3;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    max-height: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
}

#crest {
    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 5000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: 3;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }

    to {
        transform: rotateY(360deg);
    }
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) {
    body {
        font-size: 24px;
    }
}       
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 1025px) {
    body {
        font-size: 32px;
    }
}   
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 3840px) (
    body {
        font-size: 48px;
    }
}       
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wholeScreen">
   <div id="headerDiv">
     <h1>Coat of Arms</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="field__items">
        <div class="field__item">
          <object id="crest" title="Government of Western Australia" alt="Western Australian Coat of Arms" data="coa.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML,css and SVG to the question and not a link to off-site resources

Comment: A StackOverflow SSCCE is: [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: An `object` element does not size itself to the dimensions of its content (same as an iframe wouldn't), if(?) that's what you are asking. Why are you using an object to embed an SVG image in the first place?

Comment: Following @CBroe, If the SVG only has static content, so no animations and no interactive parts you can just use a img element. Then I think it behaves more like you would expect.

Comment: Need an OBJECT tag for the external CSS Stylesheet (I need and externa;lCSS stylesheet) to expose SVG styling to Javascript) The object tag is taking up 100% width of it's parent container. Is there anyway to say "Ok, you scaled your SVG height  AND width down, how about reducing the width of the OBJECT so that it can float/align left in its parent DIV"?

Comment: `object` is a lot like `iframe` and has similar problems. If you want that kind of control, you'll likely need to embed the svg in the document directly either by making it part of the page source or by using javascript to retrieve and insert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work: -

```
.field_item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    flex-basis: 20%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    max-height: 100%;
}

<body>
    <div class="wholeScreen">
        <div id="headerDiv">
            <div class="field_item" style="width:100%; height:100%; justify-content: left;">
                <object id="header-crest" title="Government of Western Australia" alt="Western Australian Coat of Arms" data="coa.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h1>Heading</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>menu</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```